# How to create layout with android's different display size

Tags: android, layout, size

My problem born when i create layout in xml file from graphics tool. RelativeLayout is awful! i don't know which layout to use.. When i put an imageview and a imagebutton, in emulator will displayed in a bad way, one apon the other. what can i do? is there a good tutorial on which i can learn how to resize image and layout in percent of different displays size?
i Try this :

```
 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/testotrova" android:layout_width="243dp" android:layout_height="48dp"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/info" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but when i display it isn't good

Comment: could you add some image on what you are trying to achieve?
try removing LinearLayout, as it is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding support for multiple screens, have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).
You will need to add different layouts for screen size small, normal and large.

Answer (score 1):

They are displayed one upon the other because you are using RelativeLayour and they are both (Image and text) anchored to the upper left:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

I strongly suggest you to use LinearLayout if you have only a few items. (http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/4/)

For your image size, if you want a percent, please use:

```
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html

Comment: actually one is alignParentRight and the other one alignParentLeft, but I think that the Button is taking to much space to fit in the space left by the ImageView which is the only element with a fixed size.